# Android: What is the best way to avoid code duplication when several screens of the app have similar layout?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

My application has several screens, and each of them has almost the same layout.

I know I can use the "include" tag in xml to avoid rewriting the same layout again, but I also do not want to duplicate the java code of setting the behavior/properties of views and layouts.
What is the best practice to be more organized in this case?

Edit: For example in several screens, the first half of the layout is a gallery that scrolls horizontally with text below it. This is the same throughout my app

Comment: having a similar layout doesn't mean the code is anywhere near the same.

Comment: In my case, it is the same. For example in several screens, the first half of the layout is a gallery that scrolls horizontally with text below it. This is the same throughout my app

Comment: so create it in a different file, and import it where needed

Comment: What do you mean by "create it"? Are you talking about a static class/method to handle this code? I thought of that, but felt it could somehow be a bad coding practice

Comment: Maybe put the common re-usable part of the various pages into one Fragment?

Comment: I'm thinking about that. If you don't mind, can you refer me to an appropriate tutorial that details this kind of work? Thanks!

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Answer (score 1):

If the screens are the same for example. Activity/Fragment

You can create a "generic" parent that handles the logic and use `include` for the layout.

Or

Create a custom view that uses a layout as content and you can write your logic there.

I create a [library](https://github.com/10bis/compactcreditinput) that uses this principle. 
here is a [tutorial](https://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/) on how to create a view with a layout file

Comment: By "generic parent", do you mean a parent activity class?

Comment: Yeah, something like that

Comment: I'm trying to use a Fragment, which is included in the layout file. What could be the drawbacks of this?